# gnuplot: Plot in correct scale & position on top of image

Tags: image, gnuplot, scatter-plot

My problem is drawing a plot on top of an image. The image is not just meant to be a nice background but should line up with the plot.

The plot is many coloured points representing a car's speed and position in a coordinate system. That works.

Now I want to line up the plot with an image of the road and there I have problems.

The data file looks like this:

```
-60.2501 106.115 0 0
-68.1729 98.0388 0 0
[...]
```

x-pos, y-pos,speed, ignore last number

Here is what I have so far:

```
set multiplot

set yrange [-1280:1280]
set xrange [-1280:1280]
# set xrange [-1470:1280]

set size ratio 1
plot 'BL.jpg' binary filetype=jpg origin = (-1280,-1280) with rgbimage

set origin 0, 0
set size ratio 1

set yrange [-1280:1280]
set xrange [-1280:1280]
set key autotitle columnhead
set palette defined (0 "black", 0.25 "blue", 0.5 "red", 0.75 "yellow", 1 "green")
plot 'output.txt' using 1:2:3 with points palette pt 6 ps 0.1

unset multiplot
```

Sadly along the x-axis it is not lined up:

[image]

By adjusting some numbers I can kind of line it up but that is just random guessing.

I tried adding this after the *set multiplot* :

```
set lmargin at screen 0.1
set rmargin at screen 0.98
set tmargin at screen 0.98
set bmargin at screen 0.2
```

which results in a bit of a better fit but now the scale is wrong?

[image]

Also the road image disappears when zooming in by selecting a rectangle with RMB?

[Here](http://pastebin.com/Nqu0WLkd) is a link to an example data file.

Track image:
[image: Track image]

Comment: For me, the image, which is now included in the question, looks good. The speed information and the track align quite good. Which scale do you mean? The zooming stuff is a problem of the `multiplot` mode, only the last plot is replotted when zooming...

Comment: ups, I am sorry. Indeed it does line up. Seems I have looked at these graphics for too long and confused myself. Can the multiplot problem be solved somehow, maybe by doing the script in a different way without multiplot? (or should i post a new question?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `multiplot` for this, just plot the two files with a single `plot` command (Thanks for the hint `:)`):

```
reset
set size ratio 1
set autoscale fix
set key above autotitle columnhead
set palette defined (0 "black", 0.25 "blue", 0.5 "red", 0.75 "yellow", 1 "green")
plot 'BL.jpg' binary filetype=jpg center=(0,0) with rgbimage notitle,\
     'output.txt' using 1:2:3 with points palette pt 6 ps 0.1 title columnheader(1)
```

This gives:

[image]

Notes:

- `set autoscale fix` uses tight ranges (for `x`, `y` and `cb`), without expanding to the next tic.
- Using `center=(0,0)` removes the last explicit dependency on the exact image dimensions