# Gnuplot script produces picture with black background instead of expected picture

Tags: background, gnuplot

This is part of a gnuplot script I use:

```
set terminal png transparent
#plot "back.png" binary filetype=png w rgbimage
filename = "/MyData/MyRadio/ND/Server/GNUPlot/anim/map_".i.".dat"
plotfile = "/MyData/MyRadio/ND/Server/GNUPlot/anim/graph_".i.".png"
set output plotfile
set ylabel "Latitude"
set xlabel "Longitude"
set cbrange [0.5e9:3e9]
set palette defined (0.5 "blue", 1 "green",1.5 "yellow", 2.1 "orange", 3 "red")
plot 'back.png' binary filetype=png center=(0,0) with rgbimage notitle, \
filename using  2:3:4 title columnheader(1) with points pt 7 ps 2 palette
set output
i=i+1
if (i <= n) reread
```

However, it produces a `.png` file with black background instead of a picture:

[image: like this].

Comment: are you sure you didn't mistype `'back.png'` intead of `plotfile` ?

Comment: Yes I am sure, i guided example like this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18738752/gnuplot-plot-in-correct-scale-position-on-top-of-image)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of important negotiations, if You need to create animated `.gif` like this [out.gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZN3bb.gif) whith constant image on the background, You can use this `code.plt`:

```
reset
set term png transparent truecolor size 930, 880
set output "outpit".i.".png"
set multiplot
set origin 0,0
filename = "in_".i.".dat"
print filename." ".plotfile
unset tics
unset border
set lmargin at screen 0.08
set rmargin at screen 0.85
set bmargin at screen 0.1
set tmargin at screen 0.98
plot "background.png" binary filetype=png center=(0,0) with rgbimage
set tics
set border
set xrange [40.1:63.11]
set yrange [49.28:62.44]
set cbrange [0.5e9:3e9]
set palette defined (0.5 "blue", 1 "green",1.5 "yellow", 2.1 "orange", 3 "red")
plot filename using  2:3:4 title columnheader(1) with points pt 7 ps 3 palette
unset multiplot
unset output
i=i+1
if (i <= n) reread
```

Do not forget set `i`(start) and `n`(stop).
After gather all out `.png` in animated `.gif` image whith `ffmpg` for example.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the colorbar, which goes `[0.5e9:3e9]`.
and the RGBimage goes up to 256 (as you can see in the link you posted in the above comment).

try something like:

```
c_min=0.5e9
c_max=3e9

set cbrange [c_min:c_max]
plot \
'test.png' binary filetype=png center=(0,0) u 1:2:(c_min+$3/256.*(c_max-c_min)) with rgbimage notitle, \
'test.txt' with points pt 7 ps 2 palette
```

This **might** be a bug in gnuplot because rgbimages should not be affected by the colorbar (since they use a proper colorbar).

otherwise I would suggest to use multiplot as done [HERE](http://gnuplot-surprising.blogspot.fr/2011/09/gnuplot-background-image.html)

Comment: thanks for the advice, I'll try it and reported on the result

Comment: did you try your script, removing `set cbrange...` and just plotting the png file?

Comment: i'll try removing all minor row, it did not help(

Comment: can you attache the file `test.png` ?

Comment: Yes [test.png](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8wLq7KFzI4AcjB1bWl6dEJ0QTA/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: You were right, problem is command `palette`, afte removing i have that [graph.png](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8wLq7KFzI4ATGVVSHEzU1BTOVU) but her problem whith axes(need range from `test.txt`), if i change axes range them resolution of `test.png` change too therefore i need to use `multiplot`, but so far without success........