# Traces over image with gnuplot

Tags: matplotlib, gnuplot

It is possible to produce a graphic in gnuplot of the sort of the ones that they like in neuroscienes journals, where the traces (plots) of the electric measurements are drawn over an image (density) plot of other representation of the neural activity? To be clear, I have allready managed to do it in matplotlib (pyplot), but it is to slow for the data sets that I have, and I think gnuplot could be faster and nicer. The example graphic is below.

[image: Example of Neurosciences graphic]

Comment: It is possible to achieve this, but how easily it can be done depends on how your data is formated and the amount of preprocessing needed. You should post a sample of your data so that we can give more precise instructions.

Comment: This likely can be done using multiplot mode.  As @Miguel mentioned, it is really difficult to suggest a way without seeing the data.

Comment: Have a look at e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/18740939/2604213

Comment: Oh, the data is just a 21x248 matrix in a common ascci file. The traces correspond to every 3rd row or so, but it is the same data as for the image.