# gnuplot: plot image, have tics-values scaled and offset (by default these simply count the image pixels)

Tags: gnuplot

I succeed at plotting an image file using the code provided in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18740939/7042795)

I get tics like `x = 1,2,3,...,width` and `y = 1,2,3,...,height` but I'd like to offset and scale these in order to get tics that correspond to a physical domain from which the image was taken.
So I want my actual x-tics to be `x*xfactor+xoffset` and the y-tics `y*yfactor+yoffset`.
How is this done? Thanks.

## Update

Here's the corresponding MWE (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18740939/7042795)):

```
reset
set size ratio 1
set autoscale fix
set key above autotitle columnhead
set palette defined (0 "black", 0.25 "blue", 0.5 "red", 0.75 "yellow", 1 "green")
plot 'BL.jpg' binary filetype=jpg center=(0,0) with rgbimage notitle
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides `center` there are many other options to control the coordinates which are generated for binary data: `dx`, `dy`, etc:

```
reset
set autoscale fix
plot 'BL.jpg' binary filetype=jpg center=(0,0) dx=5 dy=0.2 with rgbimage notitle
```